# IE: CSS Misalignment issue in UL/LI

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Im encountering a misalignment issue with IE. Below is a sample output. When IE creates a second line due to the long text, the whole paragraph gets mis aligned. Making the 2nd line pulled to the left. I want the first and second line to be aligned to the left. Just like a normal text-align: left will do.

http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v682/markeeh/alignment_tissue.jpg

Below is the code:

> <style>
>       .ul_content-l { width:330px; list-style:square inside; margin-left: 295px; padding-left:1em; text-indent:-1em; line-height:16px; }
>   </style>
>
> <ul class="ul_content-l">
>   <li style="border: 1px solid black;">Modular carpet offers hospitals and care homes a calming environment to speed patient recovery</li>
>   <li>Hygienic guarding against bacteria through Intersept&reg; antimicrobial protection</li>
> <li>Improved patient comfort and well-being</li>
>   <li>Therapeutic surroundings with less noise and less stress</li>
> <li>Use of colour and design for more cheerful facilities </li>
>   
> </ul>

Hope someone other there is willing to help. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
.ul_content-l { 
    width:330px;
    list-style:square;  
    margin-left: 295px;
    padding-left:10px;
    line-height:16px; 
    }
```

Comment: oh now i see, what i put back "inside" in list-style, it gets messed up again. If thats the case, then how will i achieve a square bullet.

Comment: there is no need for text-indent the main problem is use given list-style:square inside; for example check this http://www.echoecho.com/csslists.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset margins for `li` and `ul`.

Like:

```
ul, li {margin:0;padding:0;}
```

and than just set them again the way you want with

```
ul.ul_content-l { code here }
ul.ul_content-l li { code here }
```

Also try to be consistent and use only px or only ems.

Comment: ul, li {margin:0;padding:0;} is originally included in my css to reset all the margins and paddings. im still a bit puzzled why ie reacts that way.

Comment: You are setting padding left 1em, try to remove that and use some px value. Also try to remove text-indent and see what happens. I would debug this by trying to take settings out one by one.